# nft Quality of Service (qos)

Tags: nftables, qos

Is there any way to have a QoS over nftables.

I have a webserver and I want to restrict that HTTP input traffic should have maximum of 90% of bandwith. Is it possible?

Nothing found in [official documentation](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Main_Page).

Comment: nftables or iptables can do policing (drop) but not shaping (slow down). It's intended for security, not for QoS. You should check tc instead (or in addition). Btw, it is in documentation (both wiki and manpage).

Comment: @A.B What is `tc`?

Comment: Here's an old ( ~ 20 years ago) howto, so some parts may be outdated. chapter 9 is about traffic shaping: https://lartc.org/howto/lartc.qdisc.html

Comment: You could also check https://github.com/magnific0/wondershaper for implementation examples (don't use the Debian-based packages, they are all outdated, including in Debian 12).